# Chef - start OR restart service as needed

Tags: chef-infra

With Chef, how can I have a service start if it's not running or restart if it is?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and the service I'm currently dealing with is PostgreSQL. Stopping and starting it almost works but Chef seems to try starting it before it's stopped fully and fail.

Comment: Usually the "restart" function of startup scripts, when using "restart" as an action, first stops the service and then starts it. If it is not running, it will just start it. So I would suggest you check out your startup script and use the "restart" action in chef...

Comment: Unfortunately restart causes an error. It's not happy that the service is not running.

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is fix the startup script to work as you like, and use the cookbook_file (or template) resource of chef to first replace the original startup script with your startup script and then run the resource that restarts postgresql OR, since the resource is failing to restart, add a retry (http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html).

Comment: When saying fix the startup script, I meant check the restart function of it..They often run a "stop" action followed by a "start" action. If that doesn't work, because when running the start action, the stop hasn't completed, you should fix that. For example, create a loop that checks for process pids..and if not found, get out of the loop and then run the start action. Maybe add a timeout.. I have to point out that I do regularly use the restart action of a service resource just the way that you also do and it works perfectly, although there are  few startup script that I have altered.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you use `action :start` when installing a service to make sure it's running after the chef run, see [Service resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html#examples).

When you modify a file that requires the service to restart in order to make the changes active, you use the actions `:reload` or `:restart` (dependent on what the init script offers). It then looks like this:

```
template "/etc/postgresql/pg.conf" do
  source "pg.conf.erb"
  notifies :restart, "service[postgres]"
end
```

More about [Notifications](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#notifications).

Comment: To be more clear I have a recipe that writes the postgres recovery.conf. This recipe is run when a slave server is created and also when anything changes with the master, so recovery.conf can be updated to reflect a new master IP address etc. In the first case the postgres must not have ever started - so I can't use restart.

Comment: Perhaps I should have two very similar recipes - (update conf and start service) and (update conf and restart service). Not very DRY, but would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of the code I used to conditionally perform one of several (re)start type actions for a docker container. It could be adapted for the service (re)start situation in a case where the always restart advice from @giannis-nohj doesn't work for some reason.

```ruby
my_file = file ...

my_image = docker_image 'my-image' do
  repo 'my-image'
  action :pull
end

ruby_block 'compute docker action' do
  block do
    action = if my_image.updated_by_last_action?
      :redeploy
    elsif my_file.updated_by_last_action?
      :restart
    else
      :run
    end
    resources('docker_container[my-container]').delayed_action(action)
  end
end

docker_container 'my-container' do
  repo 'my-image'
  action :nothing
end
```